# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:16)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to frontend development. I seem to be getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./js/index.jsx 4:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
| import App from "./App";
```

Here is the code:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

thank you in advance

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById("content"));` will not work. You cannot have a 2nd argument without a 1st

Comment: Actually I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKIHpoF8ZIk https://codeburst.io/creating-a-full-stack-web-application-with-python-npm-webpack-and-react-8925800503d9 this video.  may I know how to modify that

Comment: If a video tutorial is telling you to write JavaScript while omitting initial arguments, you may wish to find a different (hopefully, more accurate) one - initial arguments are not optional. You probably want to put a React component there instead

Answer (score 0):

As most people in the comments have already pointed out, you **cannot** have an empty first argument to the function, since it is not optional. This is how your code shall look:

```
ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById("content"));
```

EDIT: `<App />` is not how you apply the `App` component in the render function, you just use the `App` variable like the above example.